# [Event]/Feed not showing the "photos" in the graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The event feed is not showing the type "photo".

Example:

[http://www.facebook.com/events/484604511557125/](http://www.facebook.com/events/311213522299865/)

This event has several pictures.

But the connection 484604511557125/feed does not show them. Everything shows as the type "status" or "video" and their is no way to get the picture url.

Can somebody help me? How can I get the photos urls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue as well.
According to my research, in case I use access_token of a user who is friend of the user who posted the picture a "picture" type is returned.
So maybe it is permissions/privacy issue, though I read pictures from public event.

I found this related bug, which was created several month ago and was not fixed yet.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/401820623197892/

Any other ideas and solution would be appreciated

thanks